# mathematic range - simple question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

I have a float number which represent percentage (0.0 to 100.0) %

```
float represent = 50.00; // fifty present, or half.
```

as an example: convert this number to a range from -2 to 2
thus:
represent=0  will be represented as -2
represent=50  will be represented as 0
represent=100  will be represented as 2

EDIT:
good simple answer from Orbling and friends, Still I am looking for something along the lines of : map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh) 
Is there a function in objective C to map such range for more complex values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
define map(v, r1, r2, t1, t2) 
{
    norm = (v-r1)/(r2-r1);
    return (t1*(1-norm) + t2*norm);
}
```

Explanation:

- *norm* is v scaled to a value between 0 and 1, related to r1 and r2.
- Next line is calculates the point between t1 and t2 using *norm* as percentage factor.

Example usage:

```
map (0, 0, 100, -2, 2) // 0 mapped to -2..2 in the range 0..100
-2.0
map (50, 0, 100, -2, 2) // 50 mapped to -2..2 in the range 0..100
0
map (100, 0, 100, -2, 2) // 100 mapped to -2..2 in the range 0..100
2.0
map (-90, -100, 20, -4, 2) // -90 mapped to -4..2 in the range -100..20
-3.5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
represent = (represent / 25.0f) - 2.0f;
```

Comment: Note that the 25 comes from `-2 to 2 = 4 => 0 to 100 = 100 => 100/4 = 25`.  In case the OP did not know where that comes from, consider it is a simple piece of maths.

Comment: Just because this is C and considered good style, I would add the f suffix to the numbers.

Comment: Parentheses are redundant in this case.

Comment: Me, I'd just use doubles to begin with, to preserve precision as long as possible.

Comment: @ShiShi: See my answer for a `map` function which does that.